# LoadRunner-WebStart Application

Tags: java, rmi, java-web-start, jnlp, loadrunner

My application jnlp is launch from Java Web Start.
This application communicates with RMI server via RMI protocol.
I am not able to record the application with any protocol of Load Runner.

Please suggest how to do this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder "jars" in a temp folder to save all the application specific jar files.
2. Open the .jnlp file associated with the application launch.
3. Locate the tag in the file. Link to all the jar files will be within
   this tag.
4. Open a browser. Paste the .jar
5. Save the jar in the above location when asked.
6. Do the same for all the jar files.
7. You will need the Sun JDK installed on your client machine (the same version used by the app) - it is preferable to install LoadRunner-PerformanceCenter and Sun's Java Development Kit (JDK) to a location using a path without spaces. For example: `C:\LoadRunner or C:\JDK` but not `C:\Program File\LoadRunner`.
8. Setup your system `PATH` (Right click on My Computer > Properties > System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables) and **append** LoadRunner and JDK to the path. The information should be entered in the following order. note that **the order is very important**:

   `<JDK>\bin;`
   `<LoadRunnner>\bin;`
   `<JDK>jre\bin\client;`
   `(The rest of the PATH for your machine)`

   **Example**: `PATH=C\:JDK\bin;C:\LoadRunner\bin;C:\JDK\jre\bin\client`
9. Next, edit the `CLASSPATH` variable:

   `<LoadRunner>\classes`
   `<LoadRunner>\classes\srv`
   `Any files needed for your Java application/JAR files stored in temp directory & collected in step (2) above.` 
   `<JDK>\jre\lib\rt.jar` (JDK 1.2.2 and above only)
   `<JDK>\lib\classes.zip` (Lower than JDK 1.2.2 only)

   **Example**: `CLASSPATH=C:\LoadRunner\classes;C:\LoadRunner\classes\srv;C:\JDK\jre\lib\rt.jar`
10. Click **OK** and close the System Properties Window.
11. To test these settings, create a new **Java Record and Replay** script, and when you start recording, immediately click "cancel" to the "Start Recording" dialog box.  Replay this script - there should not be any errors during the run. Being able to run a blank script shows that the environment is configured, and that LoadRunner is able to make calls to the appropriate executables (PATH settings) as well as access the relevant class files (CLASSPATH settings).
12. To record the application, use a batch file by setting the Recording Options as any of Executable/ BAT file or Listener.

Comment: For RM/I, I prefer Winsock.  You might also consider that route if you don't want to manage all of the Java dependencies on your load generators